# Using a symmetric matrix to solve a second order DE

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have the second order DE

$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\underline{x}=-S\underline{x}(t)$

How could I use the knowledge that S is a symmetric matrix, $S=O^TDO$, to show that a general solution to the above is:

$\underline{x}(t) = [A\sin(\omega_it)+B\cos(\omega_it)]\underline{v_i}$

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:) Hi d3V!

If your matrix is symmetric, it means, as you already mentioned, that you can diagonalize it, which is in such a case very useful.

For an $x(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, you have the following problem:
$$\dfrac{d^2x(t) }{dt^2}= -S x(t) \tag 1$$

And for such a problem in one dimension, we already know that a common solution is given by $x(t) = A'e^{ikx} + B'e^{-ikx}$, or equivalently $A \sin(kx) + B \cos(kx)$ for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

For our case, the diagonalisation is interesting, because otherwise, computing the exponential of matrices is really not funny. In fact, it holds:
$e^{-S x} = e^{-O^TDO x} = O^T e^{-D x} O$

Now, the space of solution to  $( 1)$, our initial problem, is given by:
$O^T e^{-D x} O = im(O^T e^{-D x})$

So you can come to the expression that you claimed, if you consider the vectors $v_i$ to be the columns of O^T, and the real values $\omega_i$ to be the diagonal elements of D.

With this elements, I hope you'll be able to finish your problem! :)

EDIT: the $\omega_i$ are the square root of the eigenvalues, not the eigenvalues themselves! sorry for the confusion ;)

Comment: Ahh ok I think I might have an idea, how to do this, my only other question is that I am also told that $\omega_i$ is equal to the square root of the eigenvalues, and i'm not sure where the square root comes from

Comment: Oh I'm really sorry, I meant the square root of the eigenvalues actually! This comes from the second derivative: if you derive twice, you need to take the square root in order to get the eigenvalue again, after your second derivation :)

Comment: Ok yeah this all makes a lot of sense now, thank you for your help !!

Comment: I'm glad if it helped you! :-)